# Java - replaceFirst - jump to next match

Tags: java, replace, matcher

I am trying to escape the HTML only inside `<pre>` tags that I meet ( don't ask me if there's much logic in this )

I did write this short program and it works fine, but I want to jump to the next match, without actually adding the `id="ProcessedTag"` so it doesn't replace the first match only. Here's my code :

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4;

public class ReplaceHTML {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "something something < > && \"\" <pre> text\n" +
                "< >\n" +
                "more text\n" +
                "&\n" +
                "<\n" +
                "</pre>\n" +
                "and some more text\n" +
                "<pre> text < </pre>";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?s)<pre>(.*?)</pre>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            html = html.replaceFirst("(?i)(?s)<pre>(.*?)</pre>", "<pre id=\"ProcessedTag\">" + escapeHtml4(matcher.group(1)) + "</pre>");
        }
        System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

So in order not to replace the first occurrence only, I decided to add this `id="ProcessedTag"`, so the replaceFirst can move to the next match. I guess there should be a smarter way of doing this without adding anything additional.
Excuse me if this is a stupid question or it has been asked before ( couldn't find anything useful )

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Matcher#appendReplacement` here:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?s)<pre>(.*?)</pre>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, "<pre>" + escapeHtml4(matcher.group(1)) + "</pre>");
}
matcher.appendTail(buffer);
System.out.println(buffer);
```

Note that in general it is not desirable to use regex against HTML content.  But, in this case, the tags you want to replace are not nested, regex is potentially viable.